# Can we use bootstrap library for large projects?

Tags: web, bootstrap-4

Can we use bootstrap for large projects? Large projects like Facebook, Fiverr, e-commerce site, and a project which is very complex. I just read in someone blog, which says that bootstrap is only useful for a simple web-based project where speed does not matter because bootstrap slows down our site speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is very useful CSS framework. It contains all needed responsive styles for your grids/layouts/forms etc. If you are worry about size of you CSS files you can always customize bootstrap assembly and download only needed classes (you can check it here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize). Also you can use some additional `libs` such as `purifycss` which will remove all unused classes from your static files.

Comment: Thank u so much, it is very helpful. 
In short, you're saying that we can use bootstrap for large projects also by customizing our bootstrap library.